l298P: designing motor driver using l298
I'm designing a balancing robot.
I'm currently designing a motor driver part, where I'm struggling with.
I'm using L298P motor driver and here is what I've done so far

I read the L298 datasheet and also referred to a website that explained about l298n motor driver module and had its schematic. and this is what I found on the web.

In my schematic, 7.4V comes from an external battery and 5V comes from a 7805 regulator. (wrote it down just in case it's needed)

is my circuit ok to go on?

On the datasheet, it says to connect 100nF cap between Vs and gnd(same as Vss), but there are 220uF cap on the module schematic on website. is it ok to use 220uF cap instead of 100nF?

In the schematic from the web, 12V is connected to Vcc and 5V is connected to Vc. According to the datasheet, however, it seems that theses connections are reversed.

I put those diodes because I was told to do so, could anyone explain why diodes are for?

I still don't get it about SENSE_A, SENSE_B pins. It senses the currents, but it still doesn't make sense.



honestly, the first step is to get rid of the L298. That thing is prehistoric, and convert more power into heat, so that you need a cooler for that chip, than it puts into your motor. Simply don't use an L298, and you will build a better device. Plus, using a linear supply (like the 7805) for a motor also sounds not very good.

how bad that all is depends mostly on how much current your motor will draw. But if it's more than 0.4 A, then definitely try to use a less bad motor driver IC than the L298.

Forget the schematic from the web site, the supply part is totally wrong.
